# ServiceStack.RabbitMQ compatibility with .NET Aspire

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, servicestack, dotnet-aspire

I'm creating a solution which uses the new [.NET Aspire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview) orchestrator support. I would (obviously) love to be able to use the Aspire components for RabbitMQ and Redis along with the ServiceStack support for the same technologies (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/messaging/rabbitmq-client-component?tabs=dotnet-cli) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/caching/stackexchange-redis-component?tabs=dotnet-cli)) - but I am struggling to get the RabbitMQ component to play nicely with the ServiceStack RabbitMQ implementation.

In theory, it sounds like this should be achievable - both rely on the RabbitMQ .NET client, and I can inject a wired-up RabbitMQ ConnectionFactory into a ServiceStack RabbitMqConnectionFactory instance when setting up the MQ Server:

```
public class ConfigureMq : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                
                services.AddSingleton<IMessageService>(c => 
                    new RabbitMqServer(new RabbitMqMessageFactory(c.GetRequiredService<IConnectionFactory>() as ConnectionFactory)));
            })
            .ConfigureAppHost(afterAppHostInit: appHost =>
            {
                var msgService = appHost.Resolve<IMessageService>();
                msgService.RegisterHandler<MqExecutePing>(appHost.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
                appHost.Resolve<IMessageService>().Start();
            });
    }
```

unfortunately, this seems to throw the following error when trying to publish a message :

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void RabbitMQ.Client.IModelExensions.BasicPublish(RabbitMQ.Client.IModel, System.String, System.String, RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicProperties, Byte[])'.
   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.PublishMessage(String exchange, String routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body)
   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.Publish(String queueName, IMessage message, String exchange) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line 117
   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.Publish(String queueName, IMessage message) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line 76
   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.Publish[T](T messageBody) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line 61
   at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.Publish[T](T messageBody) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqProducer.cs:line 65
   at Redacted.Api.Accounts.ServiceInterface.HealthServices.Any(MqPing request) in D:\repos\Redacted\src\Redacted.Api.Accounts\ServiceInterface\HealthServices.cs:line 16
   at lambda_method2(Closure, Object, Object)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, Object instance, TRequest requestDto) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceRunner.cs:line 131
```

Could this be because of version differences between the underlying RabbitMQ .NET client? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a version difference.